# How to pass props dynamically in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass props to a router-link which is used to take me to the update or delete page. In order for me to update the right element, I need to pass the item's id as a prop to the component(dropdown menu) to dynamically render the update and delete pages.

Here is my dropdown component:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button @click="toggleMenu">
      <fa class="dropdown_icon" icon="fa-solid fa-arrow-down" />
    </button>
    <div v-if="showMenu" class="menu">
      <div class="menu-item" @click="itemClicked">
        <router-link :to="`/updateList/${id}`" class="list__link"
          >Update</router-link
        >
        <br />
        <router-link :to="`/deleteList/${id}`" class="list__link"
          >Delete</router-link
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DropdownList',
  props: ['id'],
  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleMenu() {
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
    },
    itemClicked() {
      this.toggleMenu();
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dropdown_icon {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  color: #ffd700;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transition: var(--transition);
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  height: 17px;
}
.dropdown_icon:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  height: 17px;
}
.menu {
  background: white;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.list_plus {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transition: var(--transition);
}
.list_plus:hover {
  background: black;
  color: #ffd700;
}
.createList {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Here is my code for the part in which I am sending the element's id as a prop to the component:

```
div class="all__lists" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <div class="list">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="title__options">
                <h1 class="list_name">{{ item[0].list_name }}</h1>
                <Dropdown :v-bind:id="`${item[0].list_id}`" />
                <!-- V-menu -->
                <!--menu ends-->
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The Items object looks like:

[image]

But when I Try to access the update or delete page, the router redirects me to /updateList/undefined instead of /updateList/1 or something. Can anybody help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you mixed the `v-bind` directive with its [shorthand](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#shorthand) `:`.

You wrote `:v-bind:id` instead of `v-bind:id` (or `:id`).

With your code, you should be able to get the id by defining the props `v-bind:id` in the child. It will work since `:v-bind:id` will be converted as `v-bind:v-bind:id`.